# Import error with psycopg2: symbol not found in flat namespace '_PQbackendPID'

Tags: macos, psycopg2, python-3.8, apple-m1

Does anyone know how to fix this import error? I am working on macOS Monterey version 12.0.1.

```
from psycopg2._psycopg import (# noqa
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/myname/data-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_PQbackendPID'
```

Update: The error is pointing at "import psycopg2" in my code, and then to "from psycopg2._psycopg import" in /Users/myname/data-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so

Comment: This: `from psycopg2._psycopg import` does not make sense. Is this something you are doing or is coming from some code you are working with? What happens if you do: `import psycopg2`? **Add answers as update to question**.

Comment: Also experiencing this - that error will also occur with with a simple `import psycopg2`

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same. It turned out that the version of `pg_config` on my path was an x86 binary, but I was using ARM Python. If you use [Postgres.app](https://postgresapp.com/downloads.html), then recent versions are universal (x86 *and* ARM), and you can do `PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin:$PATH" pip install --force-reinstall psycopg2-binary==whatever.version`.

Comment: I have no idea how or why this worked for me. It did though...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. To resolve it I updated psycopg2 to the latest version:

```
pip install --upgrade psycopg2
```

I hope it helps.